# Remove scrolled part of highcharts

Tags: javascript

[image: highchats]

Can the highlighted "green" part be removed?

code:

```
chart = new Highcharts.StockChart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: renderTo,

    },
    title: {
        text: 'test - ' + title
    },
    zoomType: false,
    subtitle: {
     text: 'some text'
    },
    rangeSelector: {
        selected: 4
    },

    yAxis: {
        labels: {
            formatter: function() {
                return (this.value / 1000000) + "mil";
            }
        },
        plotLines: [{
            value: 0,
            width: 2,
            color: 'silver'
        }]
    },

  credits: {
      enabled:false
  },


        plotOptions: {
        series: {

            marker : {
                enabled : true,
                radius : 3
            }
        }

    },

    },

    series: seriesOptions
});
```

Comment: err... do you have any code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Documentation is your friend.

**Highstock Demo Gallery - Disabled navigator**
http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/navigator-disabled

**Necessary code:**

```
navigator : {
    enabled : false
},
```

**Working Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/navigator-disabled/

Comment: Thanks, I could not find how was that area called.

Answer (score -1):

err... 
quick and dirty

```
<div id="highchart">
highchart code here
</div>
<div style="background:white;display:block;position:relative;width:400px;margin-top:-150px;">
the rest of your site/content here
</div>
```

witht he limited amount of info you've provided this is all I can think of.